# Accessing variables inside Self-Executing Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript

as per my knowledge variables inside  Self-Executing Anonymous Function are not accessible from outside but how come var **q** is accessible outside and why not var **p** then

```
(function(){ 
    var p = q = 20;
})()
alert(q) --> 10
alert(p) --> p is undefined is the result im getting,
```

Comment: please format your code properly - this is unreadable

Comment: variables *declared* inside functions are not accessible outside, but you never declare `q` here. If you assign a value to a variable without declaring it, it gets implicitly declared as a global (except in strict mode, where this throws an error).

Answer (score 2):

Variables defined within a anonymous function will not be accessible outside. However in your example you are setting variable **p** as a scoped variable & **q** as a global variable. The correct way you are looking for here would be:

```
var p;
var q;
p = q = 20;
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid global variable you need to add `var`, `const` or `let` before each variable name. If you omit these keywords the variable begin global. In your case q is global